# Nginx proxy pass append request parameter to upstream

Tags: nginx, proxy

Here is my site conf -

```
upstream demo {
       server server1:31337;
       server server2:31338;
       server server3:31339;
       server server4:31340;
       keepalive 64;
    }

server {
       listen         80;
       server_name    www.site.org;
       rewrite        ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;

       location / {
          proxy_redirect off;
          proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
          proxy_set_header   Host                   $http_host;
          proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy    true;
          proxy_set_header   Connection "";
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
          proxy_cache one;
          proxy_cache_key sfs$request_uri$scheme;
          proxy_pass         http://demo;
       }
}
```

I want when I open www.site.org it should proxy pass to any of the upstream server as  server2:31337/mysite

How do I append /mysite request paramater ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
  location / {
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header   Host                   $http_host;
      proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy    true;
      proxy_set_header   Connection "";
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
      proxy_cache one;
      proxy_cache_key sfs$request_uri$scheme;

      rewrite ^(.*)$ /mysite$1 break;

      proxy_pass         http://demo;
   }
```